# Number of fixed points of automorphism on Riemann Surface (application of Riemann-Roch theorem)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, several-complex-variables

I asked about fixed points of a conformal self-map on compact riemann surface.

Precisely, this question: [Fixed points of map $h$ in compact riemann surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162612/fixed-points-of-map-h-in-compact-riemann-surface)

I indicated my idea to solve ... gave me some direction, but I could not proceed.

I found the same question asked here: [Number of fixed points of automorphism on Riemann Surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571547/number-of-fixed-points-of-automorphism-on-riemann-surface?rq=1)

Curiously it stops in the same place where I stopped.

So I need some help getting out of here! And it looks like I'm going to get a good lesson from Riemann-Roch at the end!

Thank you!